# PubNub "Invalid Key" Error while publishing

Tags: android, pubnub

I am developing an android app. I can subscribe to channels but when I try to publish I get the following error :

**01-31 17:42:17.970  17669-17759/com.thexperttech.app.messenger E/PUBNUB PUBLISH ERROR CALLBACK﹕ [Error: 127-0] : Bad request. Please contact support with error details. : [0,"Invalid Key","14227081384688219"]**

I have checked my keys twice!!
Publishing works if I use the "demo","demo" keys but not with my keys.

Comment: Shabbir, we are tracking you in your support case now. If there is anything public worth sharing, I will post that answer here.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular scenario, the invalid key error was due to an account configuration issue specific to this set of keys. Typically, invalid key errors are due to the following:

- typo in the pub or sub key which usually happens to copying a key improperly because the selection wasn't accurate (extra white space, character got left off)
- key, or app the key is grouped under in the PubNub Account Dashboard, is disabled
- pub and sub keys got reversed in the initialization
- pub and sub keys are not from the same key set
- key was not specified in the init (sub key param is there but not the pub key)

Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes to recognize the error, so just ask a colleague to give your init/config code the once over and verify that you don't have a simple issue with the keys your using.

If you have verified that none of the above are the root cause, contact support@pubnub.com for further assistance.